# Sphinx builtin themes not found

Tags: templates, themes, jinja2, python-sphinx

In my conf.py it says I should see the documentation for a list of builtin-themes. Now my first google hit leads me to http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/theming.html#builtin-themes . There are a bunch of themes in there which my sphinx does not know about. For example 'classic'.

in conf.py
`html_theme = 'classic'`

On my shell I do: `sphinx-build -b html source build`

```
writing output... [100%] index
Exception occurred:
  File "~\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\sphinx\jinja2glue.py", line 200, in get_source
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: about.html
```

sphinx version: 1.6.3.

Comment: Does any builtin theme work?

Comment: Yes, haiku and scrolls work for example.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had same problem because I used alabaster theme before. There are a few lines in `conf.py` that are needed for alabaster and break other themes. You need to comment them out.

```
# Custom sidebar templates, must be a dictionary that maps document names
# to template names.
#
# This is required for the alabaster theme
# refs: http://alabaster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#sidebars
# html_sidebars = {
#     '**': [
#         'about.html',
#         'navigation.html',
#         'relations.html',  # needs 'show_related': True theme option to display
#         'searchbox.html',
#         'donate.html',
#     ]
# }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue after changing alabaster theme to another one that doesn't use about.html. Laurent said the workaround.

Issue:
https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3987